# How do I run blog subdomain with ghost blog and linode?

Tags: nginx, linode

I want a prepare a blog using ghost in a subdomain of my website. I made a `A/AAAA` record in `linode` settings:

```
A/AAAA Records
Hostname    IP Address  TTL Options
139.162.250.252 Default Edit | Remove
blog    139.162.250.252 Default Edit | Remove
mail    139.162.250.252 Default Edit | Remove
www 139.162.250.252 Default Edit | Remove
2a01:7e00::f03c:91ff:fed5:1436  Default Edit | Remove
blog    2a01:7e00::f03c:91ff:fed5:1436  Default Edit | Remove
mail    2a01:7e00::f03c:91ff:fed5:1436  Default Edit | Remove
www 2a01:7e00::f03c:91ff:fed5:1436  Default Edit | Remove
Add a new A/AAAA record
```

I prepared settings for nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name blog.datacoding.io;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.name.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/domain.name.error.log;

    location '/.well-known/acme-challenge' {
        root /srv/http/letsencrypt;
        default_type "text/plain";
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name  blog.datacoding.io;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/ghost.domain.name.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/ghost.domain.name.error.log;

    #ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.name/fullchain.pem;
    #ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.name/privkey.pem;
    #ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.name/chain.pem;

    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:64m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-$

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload";
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer-when-downgrade;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src https:";

    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;
    resolver_timeout 5s;

    location '/' {
        client_max_body_size 32M;
                proxy_set_header    Host $host;
                proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
    }
}
```

I installed ghost using ghost-cli

```
ghost install --no-prompt --no-stack --no-start \
--dir /opt/ghost --no-setup-linux-user --no-setup-nginx --no-setup-ssl --no-setup-systemd \
--db sqlite3 --dbpath /opt/ghost/content/data/ghost.db \
--ip 127.0.0.1 --port 2368 --url https://ghost.domain.name
```

and my production settings

```
  "url": "https://blog.datacoding.io",
  "server": {
    "port": 2368,
    "host": "127.0.0.1"
  },
  "database": {
    "client": "sqlite3",
    "connection": {
      "filename": "/opt/ghost/content/data/ghost.db"
    }
  },
  "mail": {
    "transport": "SMTP",
    "from": "'Datacoding <info@datacoding.io>",
    "options": {
      "service": "Yandex",
      "auth": {
        "user": "info@datacoding.io",
        "pass": "DATAcoding1807"
      }
    }
  },
  "logging": {
    "transports": [
      "file",
      "stdout"
    ]
  },
  "process": "systemd",
  "paths": {
    "contentPath": "/opt/ghost/content"
  }
}
```

I cant reach my site, can you help me ?

Comment: "Cannot reach" is too broad... What do you test exactly and what are your results?